# Analytics are not displayed real time WSO2 Analytics

Tags: analytics, wso2-api-manager

I have configured a distributed Setup of `API Manager 2.1.0` and configured `Analytics 2.1.0` as well. It is taking too long to display the analytics after API Invocation.

- Server 1 (1 Publisher instance,1 Store instance, 1 Analytics instance, 1 Traffic Manager instance)
- Server 2 (1 Key Manager Instance, 1 Gateway Instance)
- Server 3 (1 Key Manager Instance, 1 Gateway Instance)

It seems the batch scripts run only once per day though the cron expression is set as "`0 0/5 * 1/1 * ? *`" in few scripts such as `APIM_STAT_SCRIPT, APIM_STAT_SCRIPT_THROTTLE, APIM_LAST_ACCESS_TIME_SCRIPT`.

But when I try to execute those scripts manually I'm getting a warning as

"`Scheduled task for the script : APIM_LAST_ACCESS_TIME_SCRIPT is already running. Please try again after the scheduled task is completed.`".

But the data was not populated in Summary tables until next day.

I want these scripts to be executed every 15 mints.

When I configured single `API Manager 2.1.0` instance with `Analytics 2.1.0` in the same server it worked as expected.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the no of analytics records are increasing day by day it is taking too long to execute batch scripts. That is the reason taking too long to display Analytics.

In order to increase the performance we can remove historical data using Data Purging option in APIM Analytics.

I was able to resolve above issue after purge historical data.

For more information refer https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Purging+Analytics+Data